# How to root Doogee Voyager2 DG310 & other mt6582 Devices (permanently) with EngMode?

Tags: rooting, superuser

Using the [Mediatek mt6582 SOC Engineering Mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/126314/124586) available on the [Doogee Voyager2 DG310](http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/26ef2e0c), with the Debug option `User2Root` an adb daemon running as root becomes available temporarily.

This will need USB Debugging enabled in the Android Settings.

To access the Engineering Mode on this MT6582 use the Dialer to `call` a KeyCode:[image: Access Engineering Mode on MT6582]
(You have to enter another `*` to launch the Eng-mode)

The `Log and Debugging`-Tab:

[image: MT6582 Engineering Mode Log-and-Debugging Tab]

Choose `User2Root`:

[image] Click `Root`:
[image]

If you were previously connected with an ADB User Shell, it will by terminated. Opening a new `adb shell` will get you an adb root prompt.
Until the next reboot.

So far so good. With the (temporary) root prompt available, a generic Android 5.X rooting guide *should* apply now.

I tried:

- Downloading the latest [Koush OpenSource SU-package from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repo/com.koushikdutta.superuser_1030.apk)
- Extract `su` from the APK and `adb push` it to `/sdcard/Download/`
- `adb push` the APK to /sdcard/Download/
- Login as root with `adb shell`

  - Remount `/system` Read-Write
  - Copy/move `su` to `/system/bin/`
  - `chmod 4755 /system/bin/su`
  - `chown root:shell /system/bin/su`
  - Remount `/system` Read-Only
  - Attempts to run `su` result in this: `error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.`
- Installing the APK before, or after attempting to run `su` succeeds, but complains about the `su` binary being out of date.

So, where would I find a newer, clean, "PIE" `su` binary? Or am I going about this the wrong way, and there is a newer 'Generic 5.X Temp-Root to Perm-Root' Procedure?

Comment: Have you tried [SuperSU](https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip)?  You could also build a PIE version from Koush's [source](https://github.com/koush/Superuser).